# How to "findAllBy{Column}" with HbaseTemplate?

Tags: java, hadoop, spring-data, hbase, spring-data-hadoop

I have been developing my first RESTful server utilizing such technologies as Spring and HBase.

`Message` below is the core model of my server;

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Message {

    private final String from;

    private final String to;

    private final long when;

}
```

My server should save and find messages into HBase.

I have already made research and read this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-hbase.html#data-access-object-dao-support

However, it's not enough. The tutorial doesn't expose how to find by a specific column.

Could you provide a code snippet that retrieves a message from HBase based on the following query?

```
SELECT from, to, when FROM Message WHERE to = {userId} OR from = {userId}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example to make a column based query as given below:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(HbaseJsonEventSerializer.COLUMFAMILY_FILTERS_BYTES,
                Bytes.toBytes(columnName));
        Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(HbaseJsonEventSerializer.COLUMFAMILY_FILTERS_BYTES,
                Bytes.toBytes(columnName), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(columnValue));
        scan.setFilter(filter);

        List<String> rows  =
        hbaseTemplate.find("searchclicks", scan, new RowMapper<String>() {
            @Override
            public String mapRow(Result result, int rowNum) throws Exception {
                byte[] value = result.getValue(
                        HbaseJsonEventSerializer.COLUMFAMILY_FILTERS_BYTES,
                        Bytes.toBytes(columnName));
                if (value != null) {
                    String facetValue = new String(value);
                    LOG.debug("Facet field: {} and Facet Value: {}",
                            new Object[] { columnName, facetValue });
                }
                return facetValue;
            }
        });
```

You can refer this for more examples:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=jaibeermalik/searchanalytics-bigdata/searchanalytics-bigdata-master/src/main/java/org/jai/hbase/HbaseServiceImpl.java